# execute python code from ionic (angular app)

Tags: python, php, angular, ionic-framework, rest

I have my `ionic` app where I'd like to run my `python` code as a `rest API`, I used to do it with `php` but since python has many libraries available, it will be useful for many projects to exexute python code in server side instead of php.

I have manage my `python` code with flash with a simple `Hello World` code, and I can run it, so if I run `python3 test.py` (which is the name of my exemple code), inside my browser, if I go to `http://localhost:5002` I have my result `{"text": "Hello World!"}`

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps
from flask_jsonpify import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

CORS(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return jsonify({'text':'Hello World!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(port=5002)
```

Then, if I leave my console execute my `python` code and than in my `ionic` app I call my `server` :

```
export class Tab3Page implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  var obj: JSON;
  let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'});
  let options = {headers:headers};

  this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:5002/').subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })

  }

}
```

I am able to console log the same result, which is great.

What I'd like to do now, it to execute my `python` code from my ionic code without the python code running in the console.

This will be the need in the futur, since my code will be in server side, and then I need to open (call it) only when I need to execute something (like `mysql` request for example).

This is what i used to do it `php` :

```
this.http.get(this.server + `getUser.php?&id=${userId}`);
```